# Is it possible to use two different color backgrounds in a single vim buffer?

Tags: colorscheme

I am looking for a possible solution for applying two different background colors inside a single vim buffer depending on context [like in this sublime text example](https://raw.github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing/master/screenshots/light.png).

One use case of that is to color code snippets inside markup files differently so they stand out more.

However I have never seen an example with a setup like that.

Is this at all possible in vim?

Comment: would really like to know the answer to this, I would suggest that it will be possible with syntax highlighting this post on SO may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033310/vim-custom-syntax-highlighting-background-only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because I was curious how well this would work, I've hacked something together
that sort of works.

[image]

As mentioned in the comments on the earlier answer, the only way to do this is
to fill up regions with spaces; which is exactly what we do; before write, we
remove these spaces, so you shouldn't be bothering anyone else with it.

Note that this example is very specific for the markdown filetype!

*Side effects*:

- Copying text will also copy a lot of spaces
- Using <kbd>$</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> no longer work as expected (it goes to column 80), and keys such as
  <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> also behave different.
- The background is not displayed when `'list'` is enabled
- Completely blank lines don't work, you need to manually add a tab or 4 spaces
- ... Perhaps more?

First, you need to add this to your `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim`:

```
syn clear markdownCodeBlock                                                 
syn region markdownCodeBlock start="    \|\t" end="$"                       
hi def markdownCodeBlock ctermbg=230 guibg=lightyellow
```

You can adjust the colours to your liking, of course ;-)

Then, add this to your vimrc:

```
fun! MarkdownBlocks()                                                       
    fun! s:fill(line)                                                       
        " Remove all trailing whitespace                                    
        let l:line = substitute(a:line, " *$", "", "")                      

        " Add trailing whitespace up to 'textwidth' length                  
        return l:line . repeat(' ', (&tw > 0 ? &tw : 80) - strdisplaywidth(l:line))
    endfun                                                                  

    " Get all lines in a list                                               
    let l:lines = getline(1, line('$'))                                     

    " Map s:fill() to the lines that are a code block                       
    call map(l:lines, 'v:val[0] == "\t" || v:val[:3] == "    " ? s:fill(v:val) : v:val')

    " Reset the buffer to the lines                                         
    call setline(1, l:lines)                                                
endfun                                                                      

" Remove all the trailing spaces                                            
fun! MarkdownBlocksClean()                                                  
    let l:save_cursor = getpos(".")                                         
    silent %s/^\(    \|\t\)\(.\{-}\)\( *\)$/\1\2/e                          
    call setpos('.', l:save_cursor)                                         
endfun                                                                      
au BufWritePre *.markdown call MarkdownBlocksClean()                        

" Set spaces on loading the file, leaving insert mode, and after writing it 
au FileType markdown call MarkdownBlocks()                                  
au InsertLeave *.markdown call MarkdownBlocks()                             
au BufWritePost *.markdown call MarkdownBlocks()
```

I'm not going to explain the code line-by-line, the comments should make
the general gist of it clear ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I accepted it instead of the initial answer given by @Rich because it seemed more complete. I will try it out but not sure if I will be using it because of all the side effects so no promise here :) Big Thank You for all the effort!

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius Thanks. I added it to my vimrc aswell. It seems nice :-) Let me know if you encounter problems.

Comment: Hahaha. Well I think this qualifies as hacky, but it's not as horrible as I expected. Nice job. Of, course, now that you've gone this far, don't you feel compelled to fix the problems with j, k, $, etc. by remapping them, and to remove the white space before yanking? ;)

Comment: @Rich Yeah, it's a hack. That made it fun to do ;-) Fixing some of the keys (somehow) crossed my mind as well, but I already spent quite a bit of time on this, and want to first see if it actually works at all, and if I even like it, before spending even more time on it :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Well the last time I vaguely hinted that something might be possible you went away and made it, so I look forward to seeing your robust multi-language solution in another couple of weeks.

Comment: Your answer has a bunch of spaces at the ends of lines... I assume you edited it in vim, and copied to clipboard rather than writing it to a file.

Answer (score 14):

It's certainly possible to use a different background colour for syntax-highlighted elements. Just define the `guibg` and `ctermbg` colours in your `hilight` command. The former sets the background colour for GUI Vim, and the latter for terminal Vim.

However, this has the important limitation that it can only set the background colours for characters that actually exist in the file.

The result of this is that the background colour cannot extend past the end of the text on a line to the edge of the window, so the colouring of the code *blocks* shown in your example is not possible:

[image: An example of the background colouring possible in Vim]

You can also change the background colour of entire lines using the Sign feature. (See `linehl` in `:help sign.txt`)

[image: An example of colouring the background with signs]

However, note that:

1. Doing so requires writing code to place signs on each line that needs to be coloured and keep these updated as the file's contents change,
2. By default, when placing a sign, the sign column will be displayed at the left of the window. It is possible to change the colouring of the sign column with the `SignColumn` highlight group, and in more recent versions of Vim it can be removed entirely. (See `:help 'signcolumn'`.)

For example, to adapt [Carpetsmoker's solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2210/343) to use the (more robust) sign mechanism, you could do the following:

```
" Define a highlight group and a sign that uses it
highlight default markdownCodeBlock ctermbg=230 guibg=lightyellow
sign define codeblock linehl=markdownCodeBlock

" Use signs to highlight code blocks
function! MarkdownBlocks()
    function! s:applySign(idx, val)
        if a:val[0] == "\t" || a:val[:3] == "    "
            let l = a:idx + 1
            execute "sign place " . l . " line=" . l . " name=codeblock file=" . expand("%:p")
        endif
    endfunction

    " Remove old signs
    execute "sign unplace * file=" . expand("%:p")

    " Get all lines in a list
    let l:lines = getline(1, line('$'))
    " Add new signs
    call map(l:lines, function('s:applySign'))
endfunction

" Set signs on loading the file, leaving insert mode, and after writing it
au FileType markdown call MarkdownBlocks()
au InsertLeave *.markdown call MarkdownBlocks()
au BufWritePost *.markdown call MarkdownBlocks()
```

This simplifies the code somewhat, and has fewer caveats than Carpetsmoker's version.

[@ChristianBrabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt)'s [DynamicSigns](https://github.com/chrisbra/DynamicSigns) plugin makes using the Sign feature for this purpose easier: he describes how use it to do so in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3759/343).

Comment: +1 for an answer. However (and correct me if I am wrong) but `guibg` only works for gvim, is that right?

Comment: @Karolis Yes. For terminal Vim you need to use `ctermbg`, as stated.

Comment: If you use folds, then you get what you want: The folds have a different bg colour, however, this is accomplished by filling the background with space characters which have a different bg colour set... This causes some side-effects: copy/paste won't properly work anymore (as it will also copy a lot of space characters, this is also how you can verify this for yourself).

Comment: @Rich, thanks for the answer. While it is not a perfect solution (in term of highlighting blocks) it fully answers the question demonstrating that this is possible. Answer Accepted.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I can also envisage some kind of horrible hacky script that adds in whitespace at the end of lines (and removes it again at opportune moments e.g. before save) but it would be horribly syntax-specific, and thinking about all the ways it could break makes my teeth hurt.

Comment: Someone would have to be *really* crazy to write a script like that.

Comment: Why doesn't a syntax element containing a newline higlight to the end of the line?

Comment: @Rich, with a recent Vim you can remove the sign column. See `:h 'signcolumn'`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Oh cool. Thanks! I'll edit.