# Vim only colours background of area with text in it

Tags: terminal, color, background

[image]

If I'm using kitty terminal the `$TERM` environment variable is `xterm-kitty`, which supports truecolour. I have `set termguicolors` in my `.vimrc`.

When the terminal is in dark mode, and I enter `set background = light`, the entire screen background turns light as expected. However, when I scroll up or down, the newly rendered lines appear as shown in the attached image, with only the text background coloured.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: [Is it possible to use two different color backgrounds in a single vim buffer?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/365/51) – tl;dr is that Vim can't really do this AFAIK, unless some new feature for this has been introduced that I don't know about

Comment: @MartinTournoij thanks, that did answer my question.