# Can you set multiple colorcolumns with different colors?

Tags: colorcolumn

I use something like this to warn me when I'm getting to a line length of [90-ish](https://youtu.be/wf-BqAjZb8M?t=260):

```
set textwidth=92                                    ░░░░
set colorcolumn=-0,-1,-2,-3                         ░░░░
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=3 ctermfg=0                  ░░░░
```

I'd like to also highlight the columns past the line length in another color, like:

```
set colorcolumn2=+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8,+9,+10     ░░░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
"or: execute "set cc=+" . join(range(1,255), ',+')  ░░░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
hi ColorColumn2 ctermbg=1 ctermfg=15                ░░░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
```

I don't think there is such a thing as `colorcolumn2`, but is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: My workaround is:
`execute "set colorcolumn=+" . join(range(1,255), ',+')`
`hi OverLength ctermbg=1 ctermfg=15`
`match OverLength /\%>88v.\%<94v/  " lines (88,93)`
It's subtler, and only highlights the first few columns on lines that are that long.

Comment: I [used this](https://github.com/arp242/dotfiles/blob/ec6490005d49d3515f1dfb65c8ebc92ffcb22fa0/vim/settings.vim#L115-L130) in the past by using `matchadd()`, but it only highlights cells that have actual text so it's not really identical to `colorcolumn`. I'm not sure if there's a good set the background colour for parts of the screen that don't have text (related old question with a very ugly workaround: [Is it possible to use two different color backgrounds in a single vim buffer?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/365/51))

Comment: Also issue on the Vim issue tracker for this: [Feature request: Highlight arbitrary areas of a window](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/675)